# Ascii art animation file format?

Tags: ascii-art

I noticed several format such as `*.vt` or `*.ans` that can be rendered in terminal. By looking at these file I noticed the useful ANSI escape code `\e[H`.

Unfortunately I did not find any specifications for these files. Is there any format do use ?

My goal is to write a program that displays a shape in ASCII which is animated over time.

My current solution relies on `printf("\e[H")` and use `usleep(10000)`, but I would like to use a better approach that could use:

```
./gen_animation > a.vt | player --fps=100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of popular ASCII art animation file format, but recently I created [my own](https://github.com/bookhanming/BMP2ASCII/tree/master/Animated%20ASCII) of Animated ASCII in which each frame is delimited using a special symbol.

With a "frame delimiter", I can easily split each frame in higher-language like C#:

```
            string txt=File.ReadAllText("C:\\airplane.mp4.txt");
            string[] frame = txt.Split('$');
            for (int f = 0; f < frame.Length; f++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.Write(frame[f]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
```

While this might not answer your question, I find it difficult to choose between posting this as comment or as "answer", because "comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post", I just wanted to give some hints.